# Which query is better?

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel that the second way is better as it doesn't have to convert the timestamp column in each row before comparison but I have not come across any documentation that supports that.

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, NOW()) < 86400;
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 86400 SECOND);
```

Edit:
Just to be clear, the column 'timestamp' is of the type timestamp.

Edit 2:
The column is not indexed:

Further tests:

*I ran three variations of the query on a table having 10 million records. Here are the response times:*

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, NOW()) < 86400;
// Execution time: 25 secs


SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 86400 SECOND);
// Execution time: 21 secs


SET @last24hrs:=(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 86400 SECOND));
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE timestamp > @last24hrs;
//Execution time: 28 secs
```

Update:
The `explain` from all the above is the same

```
1   SIMPLE  table   ALL                 14004776    Using where
```

Comment: This sort of micro-optimisation rarely delivers any measurable benefit, but if you really want to know, profile it on your system with your data.

Comment: @hoboSapiens I don't think I am after the actual benefit, I am just curious.

Comment: @HoboSapiens it's not a micro optimisation. Not even close. It's like the "how DB use indexes, 101"

Comment: `but I have not come across any documentation that supports that.` Wow, may I suggest you search for **sargable** or **sargable predicates** and you will find plenty of documentation on that

Comment: @Used_By_Already I don't care about indices in this specific case, my question is purely around if MySQL will convert the timestamp column first and then compare or does the optimizer already take care of that.

Comment: The term `sargable predicate` does have implications other than indexes. e.g. a rule of thumb to achieve a `sargable predicate` is `to avoid running functions on data`; not only because it interferes with index use, but because they are unnecessary computations on every row (affecting CPU consumption as well).

Comment: Thank you @Used_By_Already, I didn't realize that at all. Is there a MySQL specific documentation relating to that?

Comment: I can only find the term `sargable predicate` in MySQL release notes through this: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22sargable+predicate%22+site:dev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2F

Comment: Could you also show the query plans for each of the queries along with the benchmarks?  It may help to understand the performance differences.

Comment: @MichaelT the explain from all three is exactly the same, I have added it in the explanation above.

Answer (score 5):

The second query is definitely better:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 86400 SECOND);
```

It allows the SQL optimizer to take advantage of an index on `timestamp`.  The first query has the `timestamp` column as the argument to a function, so the index would not be used.

If there is no index, then the performance difference is probably negligible.

Comment: Also the second query prevents every timestamp to be processed by the function TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, NOW()) saving you n rows of calculations on this timestamp.